# how to install aspnet.identity code template with the latest identity version?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget-package, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-identity-3

I've tried to install identity code template using this pm command :
       `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre`
but the identity version that i get is 2.1.0-alpha1.I reviewed the nuget.org and found that this is the latest version can be installed using this command then what if i want to install the template with the latest identity version (2.2.1)or even specific version  ?
and if i can't do this does the identity template i've installed  differ than the the latest .I'm using vs 2013 update 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They just haven't updated the Samples Nuget, which should mean there are no breaking changes or anything else that required updating it. Once the Samples Nuget is installed, you can simply use the Nuget Package Manager to update the Identity Nugets.